TEN. horror movie identification
I've seen the trailer for a movie a few years back, there was TEN. in red (blood, probably) letters on the wall.
There was also a little girl (6 to 10 years old), chanting TEN DOT TEN DOT TEN DOT which most likely stood as the inverse for the .NET framework. There was a programmer involved (30-ish?) and not many other people.
The setting of the movie seemed to be some black-humour horror. However, since I've only seen the trailer, it's possible there never was a movie.

"which most likely stood as the inverse for the .NET framework." Now that would be an interesting and highly esoteric Easter egg

This is not a real movie. You've watched a parody trailer of The Shining that replaces Jack Torrance with a programmer and in which his son chants "Ten Dot Ten Dot" and writes it in blood, which is then reflected as .NET in the mirror. Here it is:




That's it! You really managed to pull the correct trailer with such a vague description, awesome!
